# How can (automatic) tooltips on fields be changed?

Tags: tooltip, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

When I move the mouse over fields with relations, I get a tooltip showing related Information. But sometimes I don't get what I expected.

I tried to override the toolTip-Method on the form control and toolTipField-method and toolTipRecord-method on the table, but all I got is an additional tooltip with the return value of my method. The automatic tooltip is not modified. Where should I look?

Answer (score 3):

When you override the tooltip method, did you comment out the *super* call?

```
public str toolTip()
{
    str ret;

    //ret = super();
    ret = "@SYS40187"; //test

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: yes. As described, I get both TooTips at the same time. The AX-like original and my text in a Windows standard tooltip.